# How would I trigger the flash button from a different button, or just trigger a different input via a button

Tags: esp8266, breadboard, pins, button, nodemcu

I have a esp8266 nodeMCU Board

I have the following schematic (or breadboard setup) I looked up my board and it says d3 is the flash button so I thought I could just hook up to it and my code would work, because my code fires on triggering of the flash button. I would be happy with using a different pin. If someone could help me with this that would be great, since I am very new to electronics.

thanks

[image: board setup]

and the following code

```
load("api_aws.js");
load("api_azure.js");
load("api_config.js");
load("api_dash.js");
load("api_events.js");
load("api_gcp.js");
load("api_gpio.js");
load("api_mqtt.js");
load("api_shadow.js");
load("api_timer.js");
load("api_sys.js");
load("api_watson.js");

let btn = Cfg.get("board.btn1.pin"); // Built-in button GPIO
let led = Cfg.get("board.led1.pin"); // Built-in LED GPIO number
let onhi = Cfg.get("board.led1.active_high"); // LED on when high?
let state = { on: false, btnCount: 0, uptime: 0 }; // Device state
let online = false; // Connected to the cloud?

let setLED = function (on) {
  let level = onhi ? on : !on;
  GPIO.write(led, level);
  print("LED on ->", on);
};

GPIO.set_mode(led, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);
setLED(state.on);

let reportState = function () {
  Shadow.update(0, state);
};

// Update state every second, and report to cloud if online
Timer.set(
  1000,
  Timer.REPEAT,
  function () {
    state.uptime = Sys.uptime();
    state.ram_free = Sys.free_ram();
    print("online:", online, JSON.stringify(state));
    if (online) reportState();
  },
  null
);

// Set up Shadow handler to synchronise device state with the shadow state
Shadow.addHandler(function (event, obj) {
  if (event === "UPDATE_DELTA") {
    print("GOT DELTA:", JSON.stringify(obj));
    for (let key in obj) {
      // Iterate over all keys in delta
      if (key === "on") {
        // We know about the 'on' key. Handle it!
        state.on = obj.on; // Synchronise the state
        setLED(state.on); // according to the delta
      } else if (key === "reboot") {
        state.reboot = obj.reboot; // Reboot button clicked: that
        Timer.set(
          750,
          0,
          function () {
            // incremented 'reboot' counter
            Sys.reboot(500); // Sync and schedule a reboot
          },
          null
        );
      }
    }
    reportState(); // Report our new state, hopefully clearing delta
  }
});

if (btn >= 0) {
  let btnCount = 0;
  let btnPull, btnEdge;
  if (Cfg.get("board.btn1.pull_up") ? GPIO.PULL_UP : GPIO.PULL_DOWN) {
    btnPull = GPIO.PULL_UP;
    btnEdge = GPIO.INT_EDGE_NEG;
  } else {
    btnPull = GPIO.PULL_DOWN;
    btnEdge = GPIO.INT_EDGE_POS;
  }
  GPIO.set_button_handler(
    btn,
    btnPull,
    btnEdge,
    20,
    function () {
      state.btnCount++;
      let newMessage = {
        action: "sendmessage",
        data: "pushed test build flash",
      };
      let message = JSON.stringify(newMessage);
      let sendMQTT = true;
      if (Azure.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending Azure D2C message:", message);
        Azure.sendD2CMsg("", message);
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (GCP.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending GCP event:", message);
        GCP.sendEvent(message);
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (Watson.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending Watson event:", message);
        Watson.sendEventJSON("ev", { d: state });
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (Dash.isConnected()) {
        print("== Click!");
        // TODO: Maybe do something else?
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      // AWS is handled as plain MQTT since it allows arbitrary topics.
      if (AWS.isConnected() || (MQTT.isConnected() && sendMQTT)) {
        let topic = "devices/" + Cfg.get("device.id") + "/events";
        print("== Publishing to " + topic + ":", message);
        MQTT.pub(topic, message, 0 /* QoS */);
      } else if (sendMQTT) {
        print("== Not connected!");
      }
    },
    null
  );
}

Event.on(
  Event.CLOUD_CONNECTED,
  function () {
    online = true;
    Shadow.update(0, { ram_total: Sys.total_ram() });
  },
  null
);

Event.on(
  Event.CLOUD_DISCONNECTED,
  function () {
    online = false;
  },
  null
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical through-hole PCB pushbutton switch. This one is by [Wurth Elektronik](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1804042.pdf).*

You have wired your yellow and red through pins 1 and 3 which are permanently connected.

Try a diagonal connection so that you are guaranteed to have a connection to each side of the switch.

Datasheets are your friends and component companies that supply datasheets are where you should be buying!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will consider that when I purchase from now on.